# Anaconda spyder (3.7.6) AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'Tk'

Tags: python, tkinter

mi ide spyder tiene el siguiente error al correr programas de tkinter

lo importa sin error pero al correr el programa solo no funciona

este es mi codigo

```
import tkinter as tk
tk = tk.Tk()
tk.label(tk, text="hola")
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu error lo produce la primera linea  `tk = tk.Tk()` luego al ingresar `tk.label(tk, text="hola")` le estas indicando que dentro de la ventana busque la clase llamada `Label` y esta no se encuentra por lo tanto lanza error.

Cambia el nombre de tu ventana.

```
import tkinter as tk
ventana = tk.Tk()
tk.label(ventana, text="hola").pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que tienes mal la estructura de tu Widget de etiqueta, corrigiendola quedaría de este modo:

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()
ejemplo=tk.Label(app, text="hola")
ejemplo.pack()
tk.mainloop()
```

Un consejo si recién estas empezando en esto, puedes buscar las funciones que importas, como esta `tk.Label`suele aparecer la manera correcta de invocarla, o su estructura y demás detalles, te dejo el enlace de donde saqué la estructura [Estructura del tk.label](https://www.delftstack.com/es/tutorial/tkinter-tutorial/tkinter-label/),espero haberte ayudado.